# Chinese word for X chair in a musical group when it isn't 1st or 2nd chair

Tags: translation, vocabulary, word-requests

In English, in an orchestra one might say that one's chair position is `2nd Violin, 5th chair`. The 2nd Violin part is easy to say: `第二小提琴`. But the 5th chair part is troubling. My question is the Chinese way to say `X` chair where `X` is larger than 2?

I've asked a number of native Chinese speakers but they were also stymied. I'm aware that 1st chair and 2nd chair are 首席 and 副首席.

EDIT: What I mean by `chair` is a ranking of skill within the section. It is **not** very related to the row. An example

> (1st row contains 1violin-1stchair, 2v-1c, 1v-2c, and 2v-2c)

can be found here: http://www.violinist.com/discussion/response.cfm?ID=6444

Answer (score 1):

You can just use 第X席. E.g.2nd violin 5th chair 第二小提琴手第5席.

You rarely saw it probably because if the x>2, they probably do not feel that proud. And no matter 第3席 or 第9席, even the 副首席 does not mean too much to the non-expert audiences (in China)--the spotlight is only on the 首席第一小提琴手.

Comment: Seems logical, do you have a reference, or a usage example?

Answer (score 0):

2nd try: [我坐在小提琴组的第三排.](http://www.ichacha.net/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E6%8E%92.html)  I sat in the third row of violins…

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Lin suggests ( In 2011 he was appointed first violinist of the Juilliard String Quartet.) he's the 3rd person to be the 1st violin. And the Chinese source says `林以信在2011年受邀加入，成為創團以來第三位第一小提琴手` or since he was invited in 2011. These seem to be referring to the same thing.

Comment: Did some more googling. Probably closer to target this time.

Comment: Although some Baidu user says 排 refers to the different groups: violon, celli, etc. http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1881870062804287308.html?fr=iks&word=%B9%DC%CF%D2%C0%D6%B6%D3%C0%D6%C6%F7%B5%C4%CE%BB%D6%C3&ie=gbk

Comment: 排 seems to be like the row. Only marginally related to the chair. I've updated my question to make it clearer what I mean by `chair`.